# Does the SendGrid Integration module also require additional libraries?

Tags: emails

I'm trying to use SendGrid for email delivery. I have an account on sendgrid.com, and have generated API credentials.

When I try to use the service I always get a 404 BAD username and password error:

> Email sending failed with 404/Bad Request. Bad username / password

Does the [SendGrid Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/sendgrid_integration) module also require additional libraries?

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this detailed tutorial](https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/using-sendgrid-to-deliver-email-with-wordpress-and-drupal/#drupal) it says you shouldn't. You might want to check if you added a trailing space to the end of your username or password?

The [HTTP response 400](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) in combination with it's text should make it clear this is a configuration error, not an missing library error. Then it would probably show PHP dependancy errors.

Comment: I didn't get any solution yet,as still showing same error...But thanx for ur help

Comment: I'd like to help you out. Could you use Postman (it's a REST client to create a request following this: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html) and check if the request is the same in PHP as in the client?